# return-key not working for many textareas

Tags: javascript, return, key, textarea

I have a form that I have prevented the user from using the enter/return key to submit the form.

I have two textareas on the form that I want to allow the enter/return key to operate.

I have added this code to try to overcome this issue ([from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433827/return-key-not-working-within-a-textarea)):

```
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        //if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        if((event.which== 13) && ($(event.target)[0]!=$("textarea")[0])) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The code in the thread I have cited does not work for **multiple** textareas - only for one textarea per form!

However, this code will only work for the 1st textarea. The enter/return key in the 2nd textarea does not work.

I have attempted many times to get this to work for more than 1 textarea, but all my attempts have failed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The second field won't allow the `Enter` key because you are explicitly preventing it from triggering in `$(event.target)[0] != $("textarea")[0]`... but what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want the user to be able to press `Enter` on `<textarea>` fields or not? What is the desired outcome? That both fields are prevented from pressing `Enter`?

Comment: Yes. Allow the user to press the `Enter` on the `<textarea>`, but prevent user pressing the `Enter` on the `<form>`.

Comment: you can't submit a form using `enter`/`return` key in a `textarea` , why do you want to prevent it ?

Comment: Taki - That's correct! Also, not what I stipulated in the question / comment. The enter/return key in a textarea will create a new line in the textarea! This is not working in my textareas!

Comment: **Not a possible duplicate!** My thread/question is about **multiple** `textareas`. The other thread, which I originally cited concerns **one** `textarea`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

It does disable the `enter` key for the form submit and it does permit the `enter` key to create new lines in **all** textareas as stated in your post.

```
$(document).on("keypress", ":input:not(textarea)", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if just to check if the node that triggered the event isn't a `textarea`. If it's not, don't allow the use of `enter/return`

```
$(window).keydown(function(event){
   if((event.which== 13) && event.target.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA') {
        event.preventDefault()
        return false;
   }  
});
```

Comment: This code not working for me. Also missing closing curly bracket.

Comment: No errors. The enter key does not work in both the textareas with your code.

Comment: what do you suggest I change it to?

Comment: Your code change submits the form when the enter key is pressed inside the textarea - this should not happen. The enter key should not submit the form. The enter key inside the textarea should make a new line.

Comment: Your updated code allows the return inside the textarea, which is correct. But I also need to disable the enter key to submit the form. Your code allows the user to submit the form using the enter key.

Comment: What about now?